# Split 2D quad by line

Tags: geometry, 2d, polygon, divide

I found many implementations that deal with splitting a **polygon** by a given line, but I only need to split a **Quad** (rectangle with 4 vertexes).

Is there an algorithm optimized for this task? **Simplicity** is valued over performance.

I narrowed down 4 types of intersection:

#### Adjacent

Where the line enters one side and leaves through an adjacent side.
This will generate 1 polygon with **3 points** and 1 polygon with **5 points**.

[image: Adjacent]

#### Opposite

Where the line enters one side and leaves through the opposite side.
This will generate 1 polygon with **4 points** and 1 polygon with **4 points**.

[image: Opposite]

#### Diagonal Opposite

Where the line enters one corner and leaves through the opposite corner.
This will generate 1 polygon with **3 points** and 1 polygon with **3 points**.

[image: Diagonal Opposite]

#### Diagonal Adjacent

Where the line enters one corner and leaves through an adjacent side.
This will generate 1 polygon with **3 points** and 1 polygon with **4 points**.

[image: Diagonal Adjacent]

But **so far** I was unable to come up with a **good simple** algorithm.

Comment: What have you come up with that you are not satisfied with?

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned before, the algorithms I read were created to handle a broad case scenario. I just thought maybe there is some simple algorithm designed just for this case. Maybe there isn't and I will have to stick with the other algorithms.

Comment: I don't think you can get much more efficient than a general solution, since you'll just end up finding intersections and generating 2 vertex loops, the number of sides wouldn't matter, and explicitly not specializing for side-length-4 probably produces a simpler algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

There are [a lot of effective algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_clipping) to clip a line by rectangular window.

I've used [Liang-Barski one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liang%E2%80%93Barsky) for my purposes (check "External Links" section for effective implementation)